# Single word for the emotion of being alone in a crowd?

Tags: single-word-requests

Can anyone suggest to me a single word for the emotion of being alone in a crowd

Comment: Different people feel different things when alone in a crowd: claustrophobic, anonymous, happy, etc. You'll need to describe what specific emotion you're after. Please use the [edit] link to do this.

Comment: Alienated, perhaps.  But you really need to help us help you.  Give us some context, a sample sentence, and the words you considered but rejected (and why).

Answer (score 2):

Isolated? Adrift? The first conveys the impression of loneliness, the second adds feeling of powerlessness.

Comment: The problem i found with the word is that there is a feel of some forcing ,what i mean is that the word conveys the feeling that "someone"isolated you.

Comment: Ok, that's your take but, personally, I isolate myself in crowds. I don't like them so I see myself as separate.